# cross-env: Permission denied when deploy docker on container-optimized-os

Tags: laravel, docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-run

First I deployed my laravel project on google container-optimized-os.

And I have created the build by running:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

After it has finished to go into app container and I run:

```
docker exec -it app bash
```

I then run:

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm run dev
```

and finally I get this error:

> ```
> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
> npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
>
> @ dev /var/www
> npm run development
>
> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
> npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
>
> @ development /var/www
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 126
> npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 126
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-10T15_35_07_179Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 126
> npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
> npm ERR! Exit status 126
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-10T15_35_07_203Z-debug.log
> ```

I copy `docker-compos.yml` and Dockerfile from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose

and edit Dockerfile for install nodejs and npm

Thanks.